# DynamoDB - Query Column name

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm a newbie to DynamoDB and node.js. I have a requirement to search the dynamoDB table(say Table 1) items/column to find a matching attribute/field name(Not the value) and return the key. This could be a column or a field in the json data. Can you please help me with how to query it? thank you.

Comment: A DynamoDB table stores "items", and each item has "attributes". Can you clarify the question, and maybe avoid using "columns"?

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase the question, I need to search each record for matching "item" and "attribute" names/keys and return the PK. Here, the attribute would be in JSON format. This is not really a search of data, but rather metadata.

Answer (score 2):

This requires a [`Scan`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html), not a `Query`. Use `Scan` with caution, since it could be slow and expensive. You likely need to change how items are stored in DynamoDB so you can `Query` what you need instead of `Scan`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion,  is there anyway scan only the keys not the value and return true, if the key present using nodejs lambda?

Comment: You probably need to `Scan` and inspect each item. You will have to write your own function that does this that returns `true` / `false`.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB is designed for LOOKUP using keys and not to run a random query on the data. It is a common misunderstanding for people who are coming from relational databases and are used to writing random queries on such data.

If you need to LOOKUP data using a key that is different from the primary key of the table, you can add a [secondary index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html) to the table. You can think of it as creating a new table with the same data (or pointers to the main table) but with a different set of keys.

Comment: Thank you. Here i dont know the structure of the table, I just need to scan the record randomly to find the matching "items" and "attribute" names/keys and return the PK. Here attribute could be in JSON format. This is not really a data search instead of a metadata.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good use case for DynamoDB. Such search over items doesn't scale well. If you have a lot of such JSON objects, consider using a different NoSQL solution such as MongoDB or ElasticSearch.